# Receiving an incorrect JSON string from connection

Tags: android, json

[Data received from connection HttpUrlConnection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4THD5.png)

I get this information when I make a connection from Android Studio.
Suppose I will receive a different string to process it with a JSON object, for example:

```
[
    {
        "id":"24",
        "nombre":"Fernando",
        "telefono":"11111111"
    },
    {
        "id":"26",
        "nombre":"Wincenslao",
        "telefono":"78783434"
    }
]
```

This string is correct but I get another different string in Android Studio
See the attached image. Could you please help?

Comment: it's called an error string , tada

Comment: there is some kind of error in your server side code...

Comment: its server side issue not your app side

Comment: tnks I will dbl check

Comment: Thanks guys I fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting a Web page via `HttpUrlConnection`. The creators of that Web site are not expecting this; they want that Web page to be viewed in Web browsers that have JavaScript enabled.

Please contact the maintainers of that Web site and ask them if they have a proper Web service API that you can use.

Comment: Thanks I fixed the problem.